# Am I applying the Implicit Function Theorem correctly?

Tags: nonlinear-system, implicit-function-theorem, inverse-function-theorem

I have solved a $3\times 3$ Non-linear system using numerical  methods (post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671907/possible-application-of-the-implicit-function-theorem)), and now would like to argue for the uniqueness of my solution. My approach would be to make use of the Implicit Function Theorem. For this I would consider the function $\mathbf{F}:[0,1]^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$, such that $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{x})=(F_1(\mathbf{x}),F_2(\mathbf{x}),F_3(\mathbf{x}))$, where:

$$F_1(\mathbf{x})=K c_1 x_1-(1-x_2)(1-x_3)-\beta_1 \gamma_1(1-x_2)x_3-\beta_1 \gamma_2(1-x_3)x_2-\beta_1\gamma_3x_3x_2$$
$$F_2(\mathbf{x})=K c_2 x_2-(1-x_1)(1-x_3)-\beta_2 \gamma_4(1-x_1)x_3-\beta_2(1-\gamma_2)(1-x_3)x_1-\beta_2\gamma_5x_3x_1$$
$$F_3(\mathbf{x})=K c_3 x_3-(1-x_2)(1-x_1)-\beta_3(1-\gamma_1)(1-x_2)x_1-\beta_3(1-\gamma_4)(1-x_1)x_2-\beta_3 (1-\gamma_3-\gamma_5)x_1x_2$$

For $K,c_i>0$, $\gamma_i\in[0,1]$ and $\beta_i \in (0,1]$ for all $i=1,2,3$.

With my numerical method I have obtained a solution, let's say $\mathbf{F}(\hat{x})=(F_1(\hat{x}_1),F_2(\hat{x}_2),F_3(\hat{x}_3))=(0,0,0)$. Notice how $\mathbf{F}$ has continuous derivatives and is defined in a compact set $[0,1]^3$. The Jacobian associated with this system is:
$$
\mathcal{J}=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x _{1}} & \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x _{3}}\\
\frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x_{3}}\\
\frac{\partial F_{3}}{\partial x_{1}} & \frac{\partial F_{3}}{\partial x_{2}} & \frac{\partial F_{3}}{\partial x_{3}}
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

**My question**: would $\det \mathcal{J}(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2,\hat{x}_3)\neq 0$ be sufficient to argue that $(\hat{x_1},\hat{x_2},\hat{x}_3)$ is unique, provided $\mathbf{F}$ is continuously differentiable? Would there be a way to use the Inverse Function Theorem to do analysis of the solution $(\hat{x}_1,\hat{x}_2,\hat{x}_3)$ with respect to parameters, or would numerical methods be the best way to do so?

Comment: $F:[0,1]^3 \to \mathbf{R}^3$?

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks.

Comment: Generally speaking, the inverse function theorem only asserts that the inverse is a local object, meaning that only in a neighbourhood of the point. You can try to prove injectivity (one-to-one-ness), however that is a little too strong a condition because it is equivalent to proving that $F$ has a global inverse.